# Get an arbitrary float from a simd register at runtime?

Tags: x86, sse, simd, avx, avx2

I want to access an arbitrary float from a simd register. I know that I can do things like:

```c++
float get(const __m128i& a, const int idx){
    // editor's note: this type-puns the FP bit-pattern to int and converts to float
    return _mm_extract_ps(a,idx);
}
```

or

```c++
float get(const __m128i& a, const int idx){
    return _mm_cvtss_f32(_mm_shuffle_ps(a,_MM_SHUFFLE(0,0,0,idx));
}
```

or even using a shift instead of a shuffle. The problem is that these all require idx to be known at compile time (shuffle, shift, and extract all require an 8bit immediate).

I could also do it using `_mm_store_ps()` and then using the resulting array, but that would require going out to memory. Is there any way of doing it faster than that?

Edit: Ignore the first code snippet, I wanted the float at that position, not as an int, like `_mm_extract_ps` returns.

Comment: You can create a mask for [`PSHUFB`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PSHUFB.html) to shuffle the value to position 0 and then use a [`MOVD`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVD:MOVQ.html). In contrast to `PSHUFD` the instruction `PSHUFB` does accept a variable value as input. Just group 4 bytes to a DWORD.

Comment: @zx485 That works, but making the mask seems to take a while. It took me 3 ors, 3 shifts, and a `movd`, all dependent on each other. Do you know if there's a faster way to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all you definitely don't want [`_mm_extract_ps`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=4090,2293,1764,2295&text=extract_ps), unless you want to type-pun FP to `int`<sup>1</sup>.

But anyway, for a runtime-variable index, you probably don't want to branch to select an instruction with the right imm8.

[**source + asm output for gcc/icc/clang/msvc on the Godbolt compiler explorer**](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5AHo5AagCqgvG3kBZAMoA1AMLyZAcQBu8iMczIi4pgwYBKecPkWrJQfKbFM8gA5NBQUx0eVV5b2BBDgAGAEEFZzQsAFpgTBZQjxUAWzxmYnkieQB3BCYCeQBPUTApELSKpgAzAkwC1QZVVWAAOhjY/u4AZlVkBhEseQ4h3Txs3JYCYlUehGnsQa4RljGJn2ndQQJ8RdX1zZGmliwm%2BQB9O%2BRfccFnkQ95T4UNHV1%2Bfky8lygW6hQQeEEpE81xKPnQqBYtQqLEwwVCFSaJHkf14ANYlWKTEqF1G40mByO6FseGALDOQ2wXxk8kxBV0tFonk6tICEHsUOcBHBHiSPlszmKJAA1h4Ati%2BnFhul8E1Boqtngmjd7ndYtoABoPfpNBiocryBq0LgADjuTGMAA8IA9slbrZ4oaoKnh0A77BwAOx8OKfT4ut14Fw%2Bh1TIYAEXu80exgIKiGXDuKjdEGj/qGPFDhdDCmM2VQxnQ/UL4Ztn0ECBETRNaOmCbuSd8bWyIlaxi8d18gggTChxlz0wLBmZxk7xFyDEHVdD3gIYgy7eyydTgjuTXTEHrjeb6DzwYGAbjF2VmrV8WZD3KSzwACMe5gHlACF4GhBuFxAkEQx/vYIFTvI8KYIIiJSBU%2BCCEwz4MD4er6qEty2N4TDoJU8jpAhSHoD08gAOqsK0IRFEEPiaJojKiqk6QKrEJpmhUlo2pmgSYEMzrtm6HqhIsoS%2Bo4gZnoWaAsEc8giF66Z3BUprFAALLGCbRA60RDNEXDRLQ0TRAKrS%2BMprYadEykWVZpn5kunyyYs8kVEESFuAUrbyEpqkAtGABURyYCZE52Tqro2pGY6%2BmpiabsgKZphmWY2gemCudYp4hQotitMQLDlHgFggJ5ZohEw8jKckz6VK0JSqPCxSCUU0Q9D0tAAKwssQqDZECmBlsQlRESU7g%2BMwrQ7MSIbFsyRz5cg8iSQFDq%2BAUDkEE5TgNk2SFRG1PCmW1CYeWJxUqVCXn8AFJm%2BfQp2mbwV3Kb5XDnagKmXcZT1DFMF7BVNTI1taEXRtFG5bglmZ4Nmh7bZBHB7dG8Nxhlir/aFEabUeBGg0mMPNncgV4NazpJsgAQEIOkPZkw/JRiJf2xIWK5rjF4M7nuXAk7F5NJbag4Hltx4gQzgaXqjAwalqmC3A8KEZncxqmuaDRcG1ABsdqOpzLqq2rAlesJfo/eJoaA8DUUeWDcWpng8m8zm9P5kWRYlmWFYhTr6vmw6us49kuuPDzUMcSouvmOOtni4WCioLOrAhCQWAFLHvioCoNVNF1PUBD1rJgj4qAMCEXrLFJeDzXl2SYENEC6MwagQVBSKeMgEi%2BBUQo%2BCiDWVz4xSEAgogVChbVWvIIAyP6aOe3rmOwyElvzAHs7dr2XjWg68n8yOdM%2B%2Brp5Mi4K%2BLmjcjM7lMUB9bgS7vueMEQfYFaHogLAioahChCIXn%2BupPxez%2B4NxX3JoOZeghoaCwfo/BQz99AQiBBCd%2BwAwRf0VL9U%2BzJY5tHjvIRObQgTlGQAgSCnhBC5yxJ3eQ3cqFMCrkVOqmAYxNDwMQI4UIRAsE6FKHwg4trPmhCEGcXY8gn0ZtNGedZIEtnjJfdWA4uxvgdH2YgA4hyRT3mrKENMJyHyEXOURSprg3nForViFpMAEDdHcbwSt0C8TCu6HeBtczG0ysyfuQpTr4OpLSKuQkcFHBIJgEQUI0DZF8HkNoWQCB5AYAtQeacfBFB8RkKq8h0zyGfJYJg7wknEJwlRfOThrCYBCik3ktA1aOBYuaAg4T4Y8GtEjBm1ZcYlNURAOpvgtEozEZ8H%2BhR6kI19M0yO54xYDHVJcbUssDRGjiAoNa7cVEVGyESTwxhUA%2BnCMELZagVC0lwQUAAXm0VAuEHTjRUAiFkWJIw4LwPwIYApURFNaEcJiNS2IWIDjYkq9jfY7yWUsBShtRJBjcbVTxSlvHchYH4xoMJAneBCQtbqESkKsOKbE%2BJqBEmFHOSkzJOEMlZLJrk/OBTXmUORaUtG5ShzpmqUrDuQzGmjJNmGJecjaUdK6T0lpy4LEsy6Q0xGh0RboIlkMa8qoTFTM1DMu4hgAByihdDzLvGi8JkSsUROQFKTwxSgkyD%2BVhYpxByiYGAJNZiLLzGWI4rSEQyB7H8ScUJFxYlv7CovkwMVIyJVO0hWMVgyDVy5Q8IQRq5zEZcDVkBDBFpW7aoxSQ6NjCmBWAYDhLhPgGjWNSiVQYUqSRSxlrqOZCs4hfIdQHZ1rqJEeu9CJVxaMBn%2BuGQ6DlUw0ETMMSqMCszDTVulbKodyq1UatHbeGQvl50LvnfIAAKtgTQy6SIAEll0AAlsQAHkVXrtiCqjdINYgADFV0ACV5CbpVQAGXvfeww8hF3vvfTIfoChN3gR9NBDukEKiLS/EJVw1hISZJ7PnbwnhYOoGfGOUQggc1%2BDTioRCBd25zDwMc/KCIPCd1gxAPNgksAOlBGVEDZE4OWsqFPSZWrQ1sFqFkKRuDsO5FOe0DwFgBoWjxaVGEEapK4T49VcEagvSxvmMEPAVq57Ng8KUdIaGQSYe/ZgojqbdWQZYKgZy5zuxEKYqY2pQHOKATdbWbREKk3MfDWuQjwoY1H2EQuYu8xrQ133QUMq%2BnkixyhQgQ2ZkGPR2ZMAFNuTZR%2BBhvwtZghDWZ26r1fqlQoSbt0PoHBsCgTlhkG7dAMheGNmfD6kTDqrEAW4sOKEXBemi1vMMRV0sdSqvVZq2t7yCB3AbdZxx/o7N9LAp/DwscYlcZIZRKRHg87Uc9SwXwPZlMDy5HEsJabWEVZZuxW0/WRwNamLwKrTqWAurq/IaIjWpXdYsw2x4QQBv609UNzlYEovzRwQ5418GdiYFeuagg/cJBDSy/oWlhGQfVx2xfPbfXzuuqcaJE78ODtQlCPwWgN3%2B1bFlc1mt9qeuFtsdrPiNm3uw4yPDs1djDso4LDTotWFLvXclf2hV5adQoS60Tiz9oHS0Ge7Z97ChqgiFqBRSThqhTmk27p4aIgi4ySCG5ucIiPAOnmFCLX2RPReaGjwaD%2BmoQGeIQUWXGQfudxwrYOJFLKHgZIMkSSSxC4uCiXgBEVPTu2gF3Vo7AJ4f%2B53mzsZTWTGSyVXLXnZjicC7J/7dWnhKftt9dTn5ciE91eUgzutWetaXaqezszgGjiax9ncLgrgAXJ53hI58npXveowQMlWBefY57z%2B3jW2fG%2BhGgZgzjtgioOdYx7y5lqrBNH4nnEcpkMGPPjDZScnwfc94r5zEceBu%2BZ974X/vO%2BdGjaAzsilqBbg0toT4e%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%2BF4EYBfB6MgH5Amy9ykmkGSH3W%2BmSFIjsCgLWXEDWHjDKEEGKFSgYG6NEHEEkGx3qKkAiLaNOI6OkAdGtDVmSDVlUnUO805AgFwEICxGGFul0AmMxXSOx2xEBJ4CyJyJAlIHyO0h6GUgWIDGUi4FoADGtHKOUksnKMJMaNIGaLakMmiNJM6O6N6NIH6MGNIGGLGJmLaCmIgGNOIBAHLmQFoGtFICWJWMoHWNJM2LygGleP2O6kOOOOuL6jDSuNJJuMsBiQsB6NJKeOQBeJ%2BLeMWA%2BNJK%2BNeL%2BLYABNxCBM6GfFBL5A6OwwI2hNhKgIRLiTgK8CIVbHRMxLsBxNSPxNCPCMiI1NiLJKkApKpJpNCBTRtJ6GamiDMCZOsC5KhHZJ1U5OGCO0SP4H5NOMFOISwjaEoBrKkGVNVPVPaK1KEB1L1NyKFIKOajFOlMlOlNlPlOiEVLCKkCGDrJXOkAnP1MNNvKQHNNNPNJQHrmADVlaPtKiUdI2K2LdKjI9Nk0WCOJzR9IuOAH9IbMDLuJDMeIdGeNaHdPeNPIbPjKjMTPYF5OBPTPgHBOzKhKkGSAdHmnhLtygLzKLJRNLICHLOxKEFxIkDoHnOJPrLiPJMpOpNUh%2BzVk7M7J7PwD7NZIHI5PwWGCGEcDHN4GvM3OFNoE7OUgyIsnKO0nKNoCGFqLaiVKaJADVJJIbNXJ6L6IFINNGIgHvKErIAoDNLMufJqLuBpLtLyAdLWO/NdJOL2IOPSAICApOIgt9MuMkADJYSDPuNDIbPDMjL2MQs%2BOWG%2BN%2BMYH%2BM4BTIEDTIzJwpiRzPwv3RjCMFMGSGLKQDlkrLxIYsJKYsvKbLYtbLyxqPkF0mlPkGvWXWIl4uZPci2DZLMvSNzx5MSskqnPAKTjnI0pVK0uXM1KvLXIMsnLyIKJkosnkuUkUuPJUrUsJPPJ0pYq6N1IFPnK4AvLGs2o3MFL42uWiOUiAA) for all the functions in this answer.  **Including (at the bottom) some test callers that use a compile-time constant idx so you can see what will happen when inlining + constant-propagation happens in your real program**.  And/or two indices from the same vector (only gcc CSEs and reloads twice from the same store, other compilers store twice).

**Store/reload optimizes with gcc/clang/ICC** (but the variable-idx version is higher latency).  **Other ways only optimize nicely for constant inputs with clang**.  (clang can even see through the `pshufb` version and turn it into `vshufps imm8` or `vpermilps imm8`, or a no-op for idx=0).  Other compilers do stupid stuff like zeroing a vector with `vxorps` and using that as a `vpermilps` control!

---

### 128-bit vectors: use a variable-shuffle if you have SSSE3 `pshufb`, or AVX

**With AVX1 you can do it in only 2 ALU uops for 128-bit vectors using `vpermilps`**, which is a variable-shuffle that uses dword selector elements, unlike `pshufb`.

This lets you do exactly the same shuffle as your `_mm_shuffle_ps` (including copying the low element to the upper 3 elements which is fine), but with a runtime index instead of an immediate.

```
// you can pass vectors by value.  Not that it matters when inlining
static inline
float get128_avx(__m128i a, int idx){
    __m128i vidx = _mm_cvtsi32_si128(idx);          // vmovd
    __m128  shuffled = _mm_permutevar_ps(a, vidx);  // vpermilps
    return _mm_cvtss_f32(shuffled);
}
```

gcc and clang compile it like this for x86-64 (Godbolt compiler explorer):

```
    vmovd           xmm1, edi
    vpermilps       xmm0, xmm0, xmm1
    ret
```

---

**Without AVX but with SSSE3, you can load or create a mask for `pshufb`**.  It's fairly common to index an array of 4 `__m128i` vectors, especially using a `_mm_movemask_ps` result as an index.  But here we only care about the low 32-bit element, so we can do better than that.

In fact, the regular nature of the pattern means we can create it with a multiply and add, using two 32-bit immediate operands.

```
static inline
float get128_ssse3(__m128 a, int idx) {
    const uint32_t low4 = 0x03020100, step4=0x04040404;
    uint32_t selector = low4 + idx*step4;
    __m128i vidx = _mm_cvtsi32_si128(selector);

    // alternative: load a 4-byte window into 0..15 from memory.  worse latency
    // static constexpr uint32_t shuffles[4] = { low4, low4+step4*1, low4+step4*2, low4+step4*3 };
    //__m128i vidx = _mm_cvtsi32_si128(shuffles[idx]);
    __m128i shuffled = _mm_shuffle_epi8(_mm_castps_si128(a), vidx);
    return _mm_cvtss_f32(_mm_castsi128_ps(shuffled));
}
```

gcc output for `-O3 -march=nehalem` (other compilers do the same, module maybe a wasted `movaps`):

```
get128_ssse3(float __vector(4), int):
    imul    edi, edi, 67372036        # 0x04040404
    add     edi, 50462976             # 0x03020100
    movd    xmm1, edi
    pshufb  xmm0, xmm1
    ret                     # with the float we want at the bottom of XMM0
```

So without AVX, store/reload saves instructions (and uops), especially if the compiler can avoid sign-extending or zero-extending the index.

Latency from idx to result = imul(3) + add(1) + movd(2) + pshufb(1) on Intel CPUs from Core2(Penryn) and newer.  Latency from input vector to result is only `pshufb`, though.  (Plus bypass-delay latency on Nehalem.)  http://agner.org/optimize/

---

## `__m256` 256-bit vectors: shuffle with AVX2, otherwise probably store/reload

Unlike AVX1, AVX2 has lane-crossing variable shuffles like  [`vpermps`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/VPERMPS.html).  (AVX1 only has immediate shuffles of whole 128-bit lanes.)  We can use `vpermps` as a drop-in replacement for AVX1 `vpermilps` to grab an element from a 256-bit vector.

There are two intrinsics for `vpermps` (See [Intel's intrinsics finder](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=vpermps&expand=4067,3944,4067)).

- `_mm256_permutevar8x32_ps(__m256 a, __m256i idx)`: the old name, with operands in opposite order to the asm instruction.
- `_mm256_permutexvar_ps(__m256i idx, __m256 a)`: the new name, introduced with AVX512, with operands in the correct order (matching the asm operand order, opposite from `_mm_shuffle_epi8` or `_mm_permutevar_ps`).  The [asm instruction-set reference manual entry](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/VPERMPS.html) only lists this version, and lists it with the wrong type (`__m256 i` for the control operand).

  gcc and ICC accept this mnemonic with only AVX2 enabled, not AVX512.  But unfortunately clang only accepts this with `-mavx512vl` (or `-march=skylake-avx512`), so you can't portably use it.  So just use the clunkier 8x32 name, which works everywhere.

```
#ifdef __AVX2__
float get256_avx2(__m256 a, int idx) {
    __m128i vidx = _mm_cvtsi32_si128(idx);          // vmovd
    __m256i vidx256 = _mm256_castsi128_si256(vidx);  // no instructions
    __m256  shuffled = _mm256_permutevar8x32_ps(a, vidx256);  // vpermps
    return _mm256_cvtss_f32(shuffled);
}

    // operand order matches asm for the new name: index first, unlike pshufb and vpermilps
    //__m256  shuffled = _mm256_permutexvar_ps(vidx256, a);  // vpermps
#endif
```

`_mm256_castsi128_si256` doesn't technically leaves the upper lane undefined (so the compiler never needs to spend an instruction zero-extending), but we don't care about the upper lane anyway.

This compiles to just

```
    vmovd   xmm1, edi
    vpermps ymm0, ymm1, ymm0
     # vzeroupper        # these go away when inlining
     # ret
```

So it's fantastic on Intel CPUs, just 3c latency from input vector to result, and 2 uops throughput cost (but both uops need port 5).

Lane-crossing shuffles on AMD are significantly more expensive.

---

## Store/reload

Cases where store/reload is actually good:

- **256-bit vectors without AVX2**, or 128-bit vectors without SSSE3.
- **if you need 2 or more elements from the same vector** (but note that compilers other than gcc store multiple times if you actually call `get128_reload`.  So if you do this, manually inline the vector store and index it multiple times.)
- When ALU port pressure (especially the shuffle port) is a problem, and throughput is more important than latency.  On Intel CPUs, `movd xmm, eax` also runs on port 5, so it competes with shuffles.  But hopefully you're only using scalar extraction outside an inner loop, with lots of surrounding code that does other stuff.
- When `idx` is often a compile-time constant and you want to let the compiler pick the shuffles for you.

**A bad `idx` can crash your program instead of just giving you the wrong element, though.**  The methods that turn the index directly into a shuffle control ignore the high bits.

Beware that [ICC sometimes misses optimizing a constant index into a shuffle after inlining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51407959/get-an-arbitrary-float-from-a-simd-register-at-runtime/51413278?noredirect=1#comment89799186_51413278).  ICC does ok with `test_reload2` in the Godbolt example.

**Store/reload to a local array is totally fine for throughput (maybe not latency)**, and only has ~6 cycle latency on typical CPUs, thanks to store-forwarding.  Most CPUs have more front-end throughput than vector ALUs, so including some store/reload in the mix is not bad at all, if you're anywhere near bottlenecking on ALU throughput instead of store/load throughput.

A wide store can forward to a narrow reload, subject to a few alignment constraints.  I think a naturally-aligned dword reload of any of the 4 or 8 elements of a vector is fine on mainstream Intel CPUs, but you can check Intel's optimization manual.  See performance links in [the x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).

In GNU C, you can index a vector like an array.  It compiles to a store/reload if the index isn't a compile-time constant after inlining.

```
#ifdef __GNUC__                      // everything except MSVC
float get128_gnuc(__m128 a, int idx) {
    return a[idx]; 
    // clang turns it into idx&3
    // gcc compiles it exactly like get_reload
}
#endif

 # gcc8.1 -O3 -march=haswell
    movsx   rdi, edi                            # sign-extend int to pointer width
    vmovaps XMMWORD PTR [rsp-24], xmm0          # store into the red-zone
    vmovss  xmm0, DWORD PTR [rsp-24+rdi*4]      # reload
```

The fully portable way to write (a 256-bit version) is:

```
float get256_reload(__m256 a, int idx) {
    // with lower alignment and storeu, compilers still choose to align by 32 because they see the store
    alignas(32) float tmp[8];
    _mm256_store_ps(tmp, a);
    return tmp[idx];
}
```

compilers need multiple instructions to align the stack in a stand-alone version of the function, but of course after inlining this would happen only in the outer containing function, hopefully outside any small loops.

You could consider storing high/low halves of the vector separately with `vextractf128` and 128-bit `vmovups`, like GCC does for `_mm256_storeu_ps` when it doesn't know the destination is aligned, for tune=generic (helps Sandybridge and AMD).  That would avoid the need for a 32-byte aligned array, and have basically no downside on AMD CPUs.  But it's worse on Intel vs. an aligned store because it costs extra uops, assuming the cost of aligning the stack can be amortized over many get() operations.  (Functions using `__m256` sometimes end up aligning the stack anyway, so you might already be paying the cost.)  You should probably just use an aligned array unless you're tuning only for Bulldozer, Ryzen, and Sandybridge or something.

---

**Footnote 1: `_mm_extract_ps` returns the FP bit-pattern as an `int`**.  The underlying asm instruction ([`extractps r/m32, xmm, imm8`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/EXTRACTPS.html)) could be useful to store a float to memory, but not to shuffle an element to the bottom of an XMM register.  It's the FP version of `pextrd r/m32, xmm, imm8`.

So your function is actually casting the integer bit pattern to FP, with a compiler-generated `cvtsi2ss`, because C allows implicit casting from `int` to `float`.

Comment: Hi Peter, stumbled upon this great answer and I was wondering how you could (please) update it for avx512? Would you prefer I create another question (maybe there's already one?)?

Comment: @TouisteurEmporteUneVache:  `_mm512_store_ps` into an aligned array should compile decently, and might optimize to a shuffle.  Or manually shuffle by porting the `__AVX2__`  version with `_mm512_permutexvar_ps(vidx512, a)`.  The same strategy (integer in the low SIMD element for a shuffle) works identically with AVX-512, and is still efficient.

Comment: Hi @PeterCordes you've made my day. I wanted to get that value from a zmm register so I could broadcast it... But _mm512_permutexvar_ps(vidx512, a) https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpermps does it in one operation! If I broadcast in vidx512 the index (0-15) of the element (_m512_set1_epi32) I want to broadcast from a (let's the seventh, so  _m512_set1_epi32(7) should put a[7] in every 32b float lane of the result. Even better '... the third operand can be a ZMM register, a 512-bit memory location or a 512-bit vector broadcasted from a 32-bit memory location.' so it all fits. Thanks a lot!